# Re-enabling a Google Account on a device

Tags: google-account

I use Google two-factor authentication, so I am using application passwords for my devices (namely my phone). To protect my privacy, I disabled the account for my phone when I brought it to the service. While it would have been enough to remove the application password, I accidentally removed access from the device itself. Now Google doesn't allow me to log in even if I generate a new application password for that device. It doesn't say that the password is incorrect, it simply prompts for the password again, saying "Please enter your Google Account password", no matter how many times I type in the (correct) password. I get a different error message if I type in an incorrect password.

What should I do in this case? How to make Google allow me to log in to my phone again?

Comment: This probably is a better question for [android.se], [apple.se], or [windowsphone.se], depending on what phone you have.

Comment: The problem is prpbably on the server side, and not phone specific. That's why I asked it here.

Comment: Possibly. I'm just trying to get you the help you need. I suspect there's something you're going to need to do on your device to re-activate it. The only thing I can think to do on the server side is to temporarily de-activate 2FA, re-establish your device, then re-activate.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official troubleshooter to guide users having problems with 2 step verification. Follow the next link to go to it:

[Problems signing in with 2-Step verification? - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/3141849?hl=en)

Below are the start point of the referred troubleshooter.

> ## How are you trying to access your Google Account?
>
> - Mail on my iPhone or iPad
> - Mail app on my Mac computer
> - Microsoft Outlook
> - Mail app on my BlackBerry
> - Mail app on my Windows phone
> - Other apps on mobile device